# copy table content from confluence page to text file using python

Tags: python, confluence

On my confluence page I have one table like below image and I want to extract the table data and copy that into the text file.

I have some basic knowledge of python so, I would like to do it with python.

It will be great help if someone help me to start with.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the existing libs like https://github.com/atlassian-api/atlassian-python-api to operate on Confluence content. Just get the page object and its BODY that contains this table. Then parse body HTML to get this table data and save it as required.